# How Java.util.Scanner reader allow Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

please let me know how to allow empty data ?

My input data :

```
4,Get,NULL,,0,2015/05/14 11:06:26,2015/05/14 11:06:28
```

Output Error :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2015/05/14 11:06:26"
```

My Code:

```
public List<Row> getListFileData() {

     File file = new File(file.txt);

     FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

     Scanner in = new Scanner(fr);

     while (in.hasNext()) {
  try{
     String line = in.nextLine().replace("\"", ""); // here line like 4,Get,NULL,,0,2015/05/14 11:06:26,2015/05/14 11:06:28

        Scanner lineBreaker = new Scanner(line);

        lineBreaker.useDelimiter(", *");

      String job_id = lineBreaker.next().trim();

      String job_type = lineBreaker.next();

     String job_state = lineBreaker.next().trim();

     String job_process = lineBreaker.next().trim();

    String che_id = lineBreaker.next().trim();

    int job_step =Integer.valueOf(lineBreaker.next().trim()); //here error numberformat excception 

 }catch(NullpointerException ex){
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }



 return list;
   }
}
```

Comment: That string `2015/05/14 11:06:26` actually looks like a date why do you want to convert it to Number ?

Comment: The error you're getting is because "2015/05/14 11:06:26" is a date, and you're trying to parse it into an int.  That has nothing to do with your stated question of allowing an empty token.  That part of your code has already worked fine by the time you get your error.

Comment: Thanks of-course its working some time due to import bad format I need to solve number format exception ?please let me know how could I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an error value sentinel (like `-1`), or use the wrapper `Integer` instead of a primitive type `int` (which can't represent `null`). Also, I would urge you to consider using a [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close()` your `Scanner` (and pass in the `File`). Something like

```
public List<Row> getListFileData(File file) {
    List<Row> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            // here line like
            // 4,Get,NULL,,0,2015/05/14 11:06:26,2015/05/14 11:06:28
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] arr = line.split(",");
            String job_id = arr[0].trim();
            String job_type = arr[1].trim();
            String job_state = arr[2].trim();
            String job_process = arr[3].trim();
            String che_id = arr[4].trim();
            // This would appear to be a Date and Time in your sample input...
            Integer job_step = Integer.valueOf(arr[5].trim());
            Row r = new Row();
            // ...
            list.add(r);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

If you actually need to parse the Date and time above I would use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)... I think you want something like

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date job_step = sdf.parse(arr[5].trim());
```

Comment: Thanks for replied , how to avoid null pointer exception ?due to bad import file getting error like that .